# Selenium closes browser right after opening

Tags: python, windows, selenium, web-scraping, brave

I am trying to open Brave using Selenium (in Python). It actually opens but then immediately closes with the following errors appearing in the console:

> [23340:9252:1107/063438.209:ERROR:os_crypt_win.cc(93)] Failed to
> decrypt: The parameter is incorrect. (0x57)
> [23340:9252:1107/063438.210:ERROR:brave_sync_prefs.cc(114)] Decrypt
> sync seed failure
>
> DevTools listening on
> ws://127.0.0.1:53809/devtools/browser/ecce3b0e-2884-4173-bdab-2215a3d7f507
> [23340:9252:1107/063438.480:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "[Shields]: Can't
> request shields panel data for tabId: 2.  Error: No tab url
> specified", source:
> chrome-extension://mnojpmjdmbbfmejpflffifhffcmidifd/out/brave_extension_background.bundle.js
> (1)

I've done some searching but couldn't really find anything helpful.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

class Selen:
    def __init__(self):
        options = Options()
        service = Service("C:/Auxiliary/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
        options.binary_location = "C:/Program Files/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Application/brave.exe"
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
        self.driver.get("https://google.com")

Selen()
```

I'm using Windows 11.

Comment: please share your code!

Comment: My bad, just realized myself and added it

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right version of **chromedriver**?

Comment: I'm using the closest match but have also tried using chrome driver manager "service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())" with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do you have chrome installed, and secondly, does it work if you do this?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

class Selen:
    def __init__(self):
        options = Options()
        path = "C:/Auxiliary/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=options)
        self.driver.get("https://google.com")
        time.sleep(20)
        driver.close()

instance = Selen()
```

If it does work, try this to get it to work with brave,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

class Selen:
    def __init__(self):
        options = Options()
        options.binary_location = "C:/Program Files/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Application/brave.exe"
        path = "C:/Auxiliary/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=options)
        self.driver.get("https://google.com")
        time.sleep(20)
        driver.close()

instance = Selen()
```